# How get creation and modification date in Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I want to get the entity creation and update dates. Following the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36176405/how-do-i-store-timestamp-or-datetime-in-orion/36177191#36177191) question, I should get them with

```
GET /v2/entities/myEntity?options=dateCreated,dateModified
```

In another source, the [v2 reference](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/), under the Virtual Attributes section, the options are slighter different: `dateCreation` and `dateModification`.

However, no matter which option I use, I always get the error answer:

```
{
    "error": "BadRequest",
    "description": "Invalid value for URI param /options/"
}
```

How can I get them?

Note: I'm using version 0.26 due to Proton/xml compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dateCreated` and `dateModified` options were introduced in [Orion 0.28.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/releases/tag/0.28.0):

> Add: dateCreated and dateModified options to get entity creation and modification times as "virtual" attributes (Issue [#876](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/876))

Thus, you should upgrade Orion to that version. Note that Orion 0.28.0 stills supporting XML (in fact, [it will be the last release supporting it](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/deprecated.md#using-old-orion-versions)).

Comment: Thanks! It is working like a charm.
I realized that I couldn't get xml notifications with the 0.28 version in the first time due to network issues (the one I mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36263749/3011071)). Now I have Orion-Proton communication and date creation/modification.